# loop codeigniter with dompdf

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, dompdf

I want to fill an PDF with data from my database. Now this is working except that i cant get a loop in it. With what i got now it gives the wrong data in the output.

In my model i got:

```
public function getGoogle($id)  {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('quickscan_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('zoekwoorden_quickscan_google_gebruik');

    return $query->row_array();
}
```

And in my controller:

```
    $view["googles"] = $this->pdfs->getGoogle($id);
```

Then my view where i create the PDF:

```
$googleloop = '';
foreach ($googles as $google)
{
        $zoekwoord = $google['zoekwoord'];
        $volume_pm = $google['colume_pm'];
        $positie = $google['positie'];

        $googleloop .= "<div id='zoekwoorddiv'>
                            <div id='gzoekwoordleft'>
                                ".$zoekwoord."
                            </div>
                            <div id='gzoekwoordcenter'>
                                ".$volume_pm."
                            </div>
                            <div id='gzoekwoordright'>
                                ".$positie."
                            </div>
                        </div>";
};
```

Im calling the variable `$googleloop` in my `$html` variable as output for the PDF. But in my PDF it gives me only the first in the array from `$googles`, and then only the first characters of the `$google['volume_pm']`, etc

I understand if this is kinda confusing, but i really don't know how to explain this better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`row_array()` only returns one row, you need to use `result_array()` for the whole result set.